# Wiring a light to activate via relay

Tags: relay, low-power

I've got a computer program that monitors an audio signal. When the audio signal drops below a certain threshold it triggers an email to the appropriate person.

This same program can either make a post request to an url or close a relay via serial.

I need to wire up a light in another part of the building that will become on when this happens.

I am going to use single led road flares I found on amazon to be the signal light. They require 3 AA batteries. I'd like to bypass the batteries or the button on the light and trigger the light from the serial port.

I've got 5 different sources to do this for.

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

I was thinking I would need a relay and then I would probably run cat5 to the lights. Cat 5 because I have tons of it here. But I could also buy some 18 Gauge 8 Conductor wire an use that instead to make one run.

So the serial ports would wire to the relay no contacts when it gets the voltage it would close the relays and trigger the lights. Thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If we are to help with the bypassing of batteries or buttons, you'll need to let us know exactly which product you are working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is a bit of a hack up. Ideally, one would distribute the information in some other way. Might you consider locating the machine running the audio signal closer to your lights?

Anyway, if you want to do it the way you describe, then I would avoid having the current for the LEDs flowing through the long wires. Instead, use something like this with a mosfet:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyoDzX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Not sure how long of a wire you can actually get away with.